How can change Destination from "microsoft Print to pdf" to "save as pdf" in print preview option using python selenium?
I am trying to change the Destination from Microsoft Print to PDF to Save as PDF in print preview option using Python Selenium and clicking to save button.
I unable to click on this dropdown list and select the save as PDF. Can anyone help me with this?

Code:
import time, os
from selenium import webdriver
from webdriver_manager.chrome import ChromeDriverManager
from selenium.webdriver.chrome.service import Service
from selenium.webdriver.common.by import By
from selenium.webdriver.common.keys import Keys
from selenium.webdriver.common.action_chains import ActionChains
from bs4 import BeautifulSoup
import pyautogui
import autoit


def main(PDF_URL):
    options = webdriver.ChromeOptions()
    path = str(os.path.dirname(os.path.abspath(__file__))) + "\download"
    options.add_argument("--disable-popup-blocking")
    options.add_argument("--disable-notifications")
    options.add_argument("--disable-notifications")
    # Bypass OS security model
    options.add_argument("--no-sandbox")
    # Run in headless mode (optional)
    # options.add_argument("--headless")
    options.add_argument("--disable-dev-shm-usage")
    prefs = {'download.default_directory' : path,
             "download.prompt_for_download": False,
             "download.directory_upgrade": True,
             "safebrowsing.enabled": True
             }
    options.add_experimental_option("prefs", prefs)
    options.add_experimental_option('excludeSwitches', ['enable-logging'])
    browser = webdriver.Chrome(service=Service(ChromeDriverManager().install()), options=options)
    browser.maximize_window()
    browser.get(PDF_URL)
    browser.implicitly_wait(180)
    print("browser open successfully..")
    browser.execute_script('window.print();')
    time.sleep(5)

if __name__ == "__main__":
    PDF_URL = "10.1055-s-2001-17364.pdf"
    main(PDF_URL)


You can't using Selenium. That's a browser dialog and Selenium can't interact with them so you'll have to find a different library to do that for you.

@JeffC, Thanks for sharing inputs could you please suggest any library for this, or it the library ok pyautogui with them?

I don't use those libraries so I can't really recommend one. I would just try some and see what works.

If you want to download a pdf file from URL programmatically, I think you don't even have to use selenium, You can easily download and save pdf file from URL with this code below:
import urllib.request

response = urllib.request.urlopen(URL)    
file = open("FILENAME.pdf", 'wb')
file.write(response.read())
file.close()


If your page is dynamic or Virtual-DOM, This way not works and you
should use selenium.


If your URL is not for a pdf file, you can search for some
conversation methods to convert that page content to pdf.

